# Jelastic GC agent does not work with Tomcat 8.5.x

Tags: java, garbage-collection, tomcat8, jelastic

I use Jelastic platform from different providers: [dogado.de](https://www.dogado.de/) (Jelastic version is 4.6.2) and [mirhosting.com](https://mirhosting.com/) (Jelastic version is 4.6.1). I have some environments on both platforms. These environments have next configuration:

- Java 8
- Apache Tomcat 8.5.3
- MySQL 5.7.10

The Tomcat prints next info to the log file:

- Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.3
- Server number: 8.5.3.0
- OS Name: Linux
- OS Version: 2.6.32-042stab113.21
- Architecture: amd64
- Java Home: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_72/jre
- JVM Version: 1.8.0_72-b15
- JVM Vendor: Oracle Corporation
- CATALINA_BASE: /opt/repo/versions/8.5.3
- CATALINA_HOME: /opt/repo/versions/8.5.3

I'm trying to enable [Jelastic GC agent](https://docs.jelastic.com/garbage-collector-agent). So I changed the conf/variables.conf file, so now it contains next lines:

```
-javaagent:/opt/repo/versions/8.5.3/lib/jelastic-gc-agent.jar=debug=true,period=60
```

It means that the debug mode should be enabled now and the agent must print every 60 seconds the info about memory releasing. For previous Tomcat version (7.0.39; on the same platform, but another environment) it looks like this:

```
Jul 14, 2016 6:08:30 PM com.jelastic.java.gc.JelasticGCAgent$1 run
INFO: JelasticGCAgent - Start Full GC : [free memory] : 181834896 bytes
Jul 14, 2016 6:08:30 PM com.jelastic.java.gc.JelasticGCAgent$1 run
INFO: JelasticGCAgent - Finish Full GC : [free memory] : 74885120 bytes
```

But it does not work for Tomcat 8: memory usage is not changing at all time, there are no any new messages in the log file. I asked supports of these providers how to fix this issue, but the issue still there. And even more it looks like a bug in Jelastic agent or in the whole platform.

Did anybody face with the same issue already? Any known ways to fix it? Maybe I need to use another jar files?

Any ideas are welcome and of course I want to ask Jelastic team about this problem.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a problem with configuration file for variables parsing.

As a workaround:

1. log into your Tomcat node via SSH
2. navigate to /opt/repo/versions/8.5.3/bin/
3. edit variablesparser.sh file and change the third line from

CONFFILE='/opt/repo/versions/${Version}/conf/variables.conf'

to

CONFFILE="/opt/repo/versions/${Version}/conf/variables.conf"

4. restart Tomcat

Comment: Awesome! It fixed the issue! Thank you very much, Bart Bania!

Comment: It seems I was too early :( - GC agent is still ran once only and then nothing happens with log file. I've checked the `variablesparser.sh` file - it's correct. I've tested it even with a newly created environment - the same problem.

Comment: the problem seems to have been solved few days ago by Jelastic developers, there was an issue with missing `jelastic-gc-agent.jar` under `/opt/repo/versions/8.5.3/lib/` so if you do not see this file on your newly created environments, you should ask your provider to refresh tomcat 8 template or copy it manually from `/opt/repo/versions/8.0.30/lib/`